# Generate random numbers with some conditions

Tags: php, random

I want to hypotize a tournament that originally starts with 9 players with 1500 chips each, then when a player exits the tournament his chips are given to the one that win against him.
Mainly there are double ups/triple ups etc, but there are some other minor exchanges of chips between the players.

How can I generate randomly their chips taking into account that behaviour of chips exchange?

I would just use `rand()` but that wouldn't work as expected.

---

For example: 
if I have 9 players I don't have any double ups. So the stacks are similar with some variations like:

```
$stacks = array(1300,1150,1650,1800,1500,1550,1450,1800,1500,1550);
```

In a scenario with 4 players there would have been 5 double ups:

```
$stacks = array(7500,1500,1500,1500) or array(4500,3000,3000,1500); //this should be randomized a little bit to

$stacks = array(7800,1350,1250,1950);
```

I hope I've been clear, if not I will edit back the post!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the mathematical operation for the random transfer of chips, rand() should work correctly, if you want a better randomization algorithm that's a little better, use mt_rand (Mersenne Twister algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your concern correctly, here's one way to do this:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $NUMBER_OF_EXCHANGES; $x++) {
  $loser = array_rand($stacks);
  $winner = array_rand($stacks);
  $stacks[$loser] -= 50;
  $stacks[$winner] += 50;
}
```

Comment: I think a refinement would be to instead of always using 50, randomly chooose from (50, 100, 200, 500, max)

Comment: I wouldn't even use a loop, or constants if I were doing it myself, but for example purposes this 6 liner did the trick :-D